# Doctrine 2 ORM problem setting parameters

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm having a problem with a very simple query in Doctrine 2 ORM. I'm sure I've followed the docs to the letter, but it just won't work. I have this:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p')
    ->from('Property', 'p')
    ->where('type = :type');
$properties = $qb->getQuery()->setParameters(array(
    'type' => 'house',
))->getResult();
```

And I get:

> QueryException: [Semantical Error]
>   line 0, col 46 near 'type = :type':
>   Error: 'type' is not defined.

I've also tried:

```
$properties = $qb->getQuery()->setParameters(array(
    ':type' => 'house',
))->getResult();
```

With no luck. I'm sure this must be so simple, but I just can't see what's wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. What happens with `$qb->setParameters(array('type' => 'house')); $properties = $qb->getQuery()->getResult()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
->where('p.type = :type');
```

You always have to specify an owner of a property - `Property` entity in this case.

Comment: Ah, how did I miss that!? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done setParameter() on the QueryBuilder, not on the query.

Try

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p')
    ->from('Property', 'p')
    ->where('type = :type');

$qb->setParameters(array('type' => 'house'));

$properties = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```